# Magento disable ordering of simple products in backend

Tags: orders, backend

how can I disable the ordering of simple products via the backend?

(whwre you search for sku, product and there is this enormous list)

Why? Because we sell T-shirts in sizes. What happens is that we set the price on the mother configurable product level, say 20 euro. We have to set the price of the simple product as mandatory. THe problem is that when we discount the product and change the price to 18 euro for the mother product. Then, when someone adds an order via the backend for the products and selects the simple product -then the order amount is still 20 euro. Not 18 coming from the mother config product.

So.... does anynone know how to disable the ordering of simple products via the backend?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the simple products to "not visible individually" if you don't want them to show up in the front end product catalog. You should be able to do this in mass if you want using Magento's mass action dropdown. Basically, select all of your simple products in the `Catalog -> Product` menu, then in the *Actions* dropdown select "update attributes." From here you can change the product visibility to "not visible individually."

This will hide the simple products, so that only the parent configurable product is selectable from the frontend.

All of this said, it sounds like you may have some confusion over the configuration/setup of a configurable product. Or, perhaps I'm not fully understanding your question :) - if it's the former, reading through [this Magento Go documentation on adding configurable associated (simple) products](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/configurable-product-step-4-add-associated-products/) might at least add some info (it's Magento Go, but for the most part still relevant).

Answer (score 1):

When I understand him correct, the problem is in BACKEND and I think magento is not able to do this without programming. But I think you can implement an observer which listens to the load_before event, then you check wether you are in the right action (of the product list which is used to show products to collect an order) and then you filter with whatever parameter

Comment: That is indeed true. One would expect that product visibility to "not visible individually" also counts for the backend